# How to deploy a C# windows form application that has database on another PC?

Tags: c#, sql-server, database-connection, connection-string, windows-forms-designer

I am trying to publish c# windows form application that has around 15 forms, 4-5 datagrids, datasets etc. I have developed this app on my PC and it has database which is developed on SQL server 2012 (not express).

Now I want to run this app on another laptop, which is connected to my network over a LAN. I want this app to run on that laptop but still use the database on my laptop.

On my laptop, the connection string is present in App.config. Here it is :

```
    <add name="ST" connectionString="Data Source=STI;Initial Catalog=ST;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
```

Now how can I change the connection string so it may work on another laptop but still connect to db that is on my laptop?

I hope you understand my question.

Regards.

Comment: You need to point the connectionString to your initial laptop via its IP.

Comment: if my laptop's ip is for example 192.0.0.1, then how do I go about doing it?

Comment: And you need to fix your laptop firewall. SQL Ports do not get automatically opened by the sql installer.

Comment: What about datagrids? will they use this updated connectionstring? I designed them using datagridview designer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the name of your laptop as bellow

```
Data Source=myServerAddress;
```

or use the IP or your laptop:

```
Data Source=192.0.0.1,1433;
```

http://www.connectionstrings.com/ is a very good resource for understanding how .NET connection strings work.

Full connectionString:

```
<add name="ST" connectionString="Data Source=192.0.0.1\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=ST;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
```

Without `TrustedConnection`:

```
<add name="ST" connectionString="Data Source=192.0.0.1\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=ST;User Id=myUsername;Password=myPassword;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
```

You replace `Integrated Security=True` with `User Id=myUsername;Password=myPassword;`.

In addition to this, as other answers have said, the server and laptop need to be configured to accept remote connections.

Comment: What about SQL user/pass? on my laptop it uses windows authentication but I don't think it will work on laptop connected over LAN?

Can you please provide complete connectionstring?

Comment: @ShajeeAfzal Check my answer. It points to connectionstrings.com - the ultiamte ressource for all types of connectionstrings. So you do not have to even bother with this pesky documentation (granted, the connection string details are a little hidden in there). Comes in handy when you need version specific stuff or other database techs.

Comment: @TomTom, I also referenced connectionstrings.com

Comment: @ShajeeAfzal, I have included a complete connection string without windows authentication. The server would have to have a username and password set up.

Comment: What about datagrids? will they use this updated connectionstring? I designed them using datagridview designer.

Comment: @ShajeeAfzal, they will if you've referenced the connectionString from your app.config

Answer (score 1):

You will need to change the Data Source part to be the computer name and the sql instance name, for example:

```
Data Source=MyLaptop\SQL2012;
```

And the Initial Catalog should be the database name (I guess in this case it is 'ST')

Comment: It should also be noted that the database will need to have permissions setup to allow remote access to it, oterhwise the OP will get an exception.

Comment: Oh yes, forgot to mention that - apologies.

Answer (score 1):

According to http://connectionstrings.com/ you need to set the Data Source in the connectionstrings to the laptop running the sql server.

Then you also must check the server's configuratoin and - open the necessary ports on your laptop firewall. The sql server installer does not install a firewall rule allowing incoming traffic by default, that has to be manually done.

Answer (score 0):

You Can Use Your IP

```
Data Source= Your LapTop IP
```